# confusion about how to use bCrypt at php user login process

Tags: php, pdo, bcrypt

I am using php pdo at my user log in process with mysql ate database. I have tried bCrypt library for password encryption. But I am confused about how to check the input password with the encrypted one?

Here is my attempted code:

```
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
$hash = $bcrypt->hash($password);
$isGood = $bcrypt->verify($password, $hash);

$login = new UserManager();
$getuserInfo = $login -> checkLogin($username, $password);
foreach ($getuserInfo as $userInfo) :
  if ($userInfo -> getUID() == $username) {
    if($userInfo -> getPassword() == $password) ?
  }
endforeach;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're showing any of the relevant code. What is `checkLogin` doing? What are you doing with `isGood`? Why are you iterating over the results of `checkLogin`, shouldn't it return a user or null? Your code doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: checkLogin is just a function which retrieves the username and password from database. Its return an array. and $isGood is just a variable which store the result after verify the inputted password and hash value.

Comment: It really shouldn't. That's where you should be doing your password hashing and comparison. Typically, the function should select the user with the matching username from the database, fetching the stored hash of their password. Then you compare the hash of the incoming password against the stored hash. If you have the users *real* password stored in the database, you're already doing this terribly wrong. The whole point is that you *never retain the user's password*.

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't*. Use an existing password library. Secure handling of password is very hard to do properly, and you'll almost certainly get it wrong.

Second: You can't compare the passwords this way (`$userInfo->getPassword() == $password`). Assuming you've stored the hashed password (it's really not obvious from the meager code you've posted) then you need to hash `$password`, and compare the hashed value against the stored hash. That's the whole point of password hashing: The hash produces the same output from the same input, so on account creation you store the irreversible output of hashing the password, and then on login you hash the newly submitted password and compare the result against the stored hash.

Comment: can you give me an example of that how can i compare the stored hash with my inputted password? I really puzzled with it.